# OperationalError: near "?": syntax error sqlite3 error

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to add two values in a table by calling functions of a file. The file has following code:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.Connection('rdb')
cur = con.cursor()
def insert(s):
    cur.execute("create table if not exists customerorder(no number primary 
    key,menuitems varchar(40))")
    c=1
    for i in s:
        print c
        print i
        cur.execute("insert into customerorder(?,?)",(int(c),i))
        c += 1 

def fetch():
    cur.execute("select * from customerorder")
    print cur.fetchall()
```

Here 's' is a list.
Having s[0]='simple book' and s[1] = 'advance book'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> insert into customerorder(?,?)
> ```

You need to change this to something like

```
insert into customerorder values(?,?)
```

The first list in parens after a table name is a list of columns, and you cannot have `?` variables for column names.